# Rails do not save object untill reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

While trying ro resolve my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800545/rails-problems-with-update-parameters), I faced with an interesting thing that I do not understand: I had an `ActiveRecord` object `restream` that references to another object `provider`. At the end I faced with the thing that `restream.update_attributes(provider: new_provider)` do not save anything until I make `restream.reload.update_attributes(provider: new_provider)`.

Why does it work so and can't save the object without reloading it? Is it somehow connected with that `restream` could be changed in some other thread?
One more thing is that no errors are added by `restream.update_attributes(provider: new_provider)`. If it can't update a record, why does it keeps silent?

Thanx!

Comment: When running `restream.update_attributes(provider: new_provider)` what does `puts restrem.errors.inspect` output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259641/why-use-reload-method-after-saving-object-hartl-rails-tut-6-30 - this may help you.

Comment: @DanAndreasson !! I've just edited the post, to point out that it's just keeping silent. No errors, no warning in logs, nothing. I needed 4 days to find this thing.

Comment: @AnkitaSurani I know what does `reload` do, I don't realise why nothing works without it in that case